# Not able to access _admin in WireMock

Tags: linux, wiremock

I am using the standalone jar of WireMock on CentOS.
Starting the server is fine but when I am trying to access the mapping files using the url:

> http://localhost:8090/_admin

I am getting the error:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /__files/_admin. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND
```

I am starting WireMock as below:

```
java -jar wiremock-1.57-standalone.jar --port 8090
```

Below are the permissions of the files in the directory:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 anurag.upadhaya domain users    4096 Mar 17 12:16 __files
drwxrwxrwx 2 anurag.upadhaya domain users    4096 Mar 17 12:16 mappings
-rwxrwxrwx 1 anurag.upadhaya domain users 6935826 Mar 18 09:57 wiremock-1.57-standalone.jar
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's __admin (with two underscores)